# Start a parser every time app is launched iOS in SWIFT

Tags: ios, parsing, swift

I would like to run a **parser** at each time I run my app on my device. With the simulator, it runs well because at each time, the app is building and running.

The project is very simple, started in Xcode a Single View Application. I added a label named label in ViewController. I then created the parser I called Parser.swift.

This is the code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, ParserDelegate {

var parser : Parser!
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Parser
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://....json")
    parser = Parser()
    parser.delegate = self
    parser.startParsing(url!)

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func parsingWasFinished() {
    //println("Parser ended!");
    self.label.text = "End"
    }
}
```

Parser is not relevant to write.

It works fine. Starting with "Start", the label ends with "End" when the parser has finished.

The problem is with my device: when I end/start again the app, the parser don't start, and I got always "End".

Do you know what I am doing wrong. How could the parser starts every time the app is starting?

Thanks a lot.

EDIT

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, ParserDelegate {

var parser : Parser!
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true);

    // Parser
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://...json")
    parser = Parser()
    parser.delegate = self
    parser.startParsing(url!)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func parsingWasFinished() {
    //println("Parser ended!");
    self.label.text = "End"
    }
}
```

Comment: First of the `viewDidLoad` will only be called when you app its about the present the view.
Since app don't really close but go into a background mode the view is actually not load again, unless you device need more memory and kills you app.

If you want to do the parsing every time the view will be display use the `viewWillAppear` if you only have one view then from you app delegate call the parser in the `applicationWillEnterForeground`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After adding your first solution i.e. adding the parser in the viewWillAppear instead, it still does not work. I will have a look on you second solution. In the future, I will have one tab bar and under each of them a navigation controller.